# Why is GetMessage() not exiting?

Tags: c++, winapi

Reading up about WinApi's `SendMessageCallback` states that the calling function must also call `GetMessage`, `PeekMessage` or `WaitMessage` for the callback function to be called.

My code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

VOID CALLBACK MySendAsyncProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, ULONG_PTR dwData, LRESULT lResult) {
    cout << "callback" << endl;
}

int main() {
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Calculator");
    SendMessageCallback(hwnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM) hwnd, MAKELPARAM(1, WM_MOUSEMOVE), MySendAsyncProc, 0);
    MSG msg;
    GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);
    cout << "recieved" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output;

```
callback
```

What I expect as output;

```
callback
recieved
```

And sure enough, the callback function gets called but how do I "exit" `GetMessage`? The callback function prints and the program keeps running but it never prints "revieved" - what changes do I make to achieve my expectations?

Comment: don't you get any exception or error in the console?

Comment: @Sirmyself Nope - just the "callback" printed string.

Comment: @user1768788 Your question title is misleading.

Comment: no, excepted output is `callback` only. code must not print `recieved`. `GetMessage` must not return

Comment: @RbMm Sorry if I was unclear, that output is what I expect - I edited the questioning a little bit to reflect this.

Comment: @TheDude What do you suggest as title?

Comment: you except wrong. `GetMessage` must not return because you not receive any messages. if you want exit from `GetMessage` after callback called - you can call `PostQuitMessage(0);` for example

Comment: @user1768788 Something like _"Why is GetMessage() blocking"_ or _"Why is GetMessage() not exiting"_.

Comment: @TheDude submit an edit for the second and you have my vote.

Answer (score 1):

`GetMessage` waits for a queued message (`PostMessage`) to be received on the thread's message queue.  In the meantime it processes all unqueued messages (from `SendMessage` and friends) but these do not cause it to return.

Because your thread never has any posted message, `GetMessage` keeps waiting.

In your particular case, `PeekMessage` is a good option, since it returns when it finishes processing sent messages.

If you want to have a `GetMessage` action with a timeout, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` will help.

Comment: just call `PeekMessage` not a solution - it return faster than callback will be called. as result callback will be not called at all. if we not want permanent message loop, but break it exactly after callback will be called - need call `PostQuitMessage` or `PostThreadMessage` from `MySendAsyncProc` .